How can we get the TinyMCE editor to switch to Right-To-Left orientation if the active language is Arabic for example?
Most editors like basic IOS or Windows have their editor switch to R-T-L orientation if the active script is of R-T-L such as Arabic, Urdu or Hebrew. Yet can't find such support in TinyMCE. Is there a way to get TinyMCE to switch to R-T-L mode if the language is Arabic for example?
Tried the documentation but could not find such support.
